# Binary search expected number of comparisons?

Tags: algorithms, expected-value

What is the expected number of comparisons needed to find a number (if it exists) in an array of [1,2,...,n] using binary search? I understand the limiting time complexity of binary search is $O(\log(n))$, but what is the expected value of the number comparisons?

Comment: You can calculate the chance of finishing in $1,2,\dots , A$ checks where $A$ is the upper bound. I doubt that this will improve the big-$O$ though. Probably only better by $1$ on average.